# What is the meaning of suprasegmental phoneme？

Tags: phonetics, phonology

What is the meaning of suprasegmental phoneme？  Is it related to suprasegmental features? If it is a kind of phoneme, what characteristics it owns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd never heard the term before, but apparently it's defined as those characteristics of a word separate from the sounds of the letters themselves, such as accent and intonation.

Given that a *phoneme* is a distinct unit of sound, a *[suprasegmental phoneme](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suprasegmental%20phoneme)* is one defined entirely by accent and intonation, and usually occurs with a segmental phoneme.

I'm not a linguist, but to give what I think is an example of this:  English has many words which are spelled the same but which have different meanings depending on how they are pronounced.  One of these is the word "produce":

> [**pró - duce**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/produce) (n): agricultural products and especially fresh fruits and vegetables as distinguished from grain and other staple crops

vs.

> [**pro - dúce**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/produce) (v): to compose, create, or bring out by intellectual or physical effort

The noun has the accent on the first syllable.  The verb has the accent on the second syllable.  The location of the accent means the segmental phonemes are different between these two words, but the accent itself can likely be considered a suprasegmental phoneme.

Many other languages rely even more accent and intonation (e.g. Chinese) in which similar-sounding words can have a completely different meaning depending on how they are inflected.

Comment: What do you mean by “how they are inflected” ,especially the word “inflected ” ?

Comment: I've only studied a very little Chinese, but from what I know I believe there are four basic [*inflections* or *tones*](https://www.thoughtco.com/four-tones-of-mandarin-2279480) -- which is to say, "modulations of intonation or pitch in the voice" -- that can be applied to any phoneme. The inflection changes the meaning.  For example, "mā" means "mother" while "mǎ" means "horse".